# Call a python script with parser arguments in .NET

Tags: c#, python, .net

Sorry if this is a duplicate question but I could not find clear answer.

I am trying to call a python script (dnstwist.py) from within .NET using IronPython.

```
public static void runDNSTwistPython(string url)
{
    var ipy = Python.CreateRuntime();
    dynamic test = ipy.UseFile("dnstwist-master\\dnstwist.py");
    test.main();
}
```

I need a way to call this and put the output in a .csv file. I can easily do this from command line but can't figure out how to do it in my C# method.

```
python dnstwist.py --csv google.com > output.csv
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@jacob-hall you can use C# Process class and pass the command line to be executed this class documentation can be found here [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx)

and you code will be something like this:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();

myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "python dnstwist.py --csv google.com > output.csv";
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProcess.Start();
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! But is there a way to do this using the IronPython.Hosting namespace? I have been told it is a lot more portable than System.Diagnostics.

Comment: Would be a option generate a `exe` from this python script? So you could only call it directly from cmd line like `dnstwist.exe --csv google.com > output.csv`